# What is the best server side solution for a real-time GPS tracking system

Tags: gps, real-time, tracking

Well, I tried to ask this question as a comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226988/what-is-the-best-programming-language-to-write-desktop-gps-tracking-system/2517608) question, but I thought that maybe no one will notice it, so I decided to ask it as a separate one.

The question is about how to do real-time GPS tracking system things; if we have the following scenario:

1. Rather than connecting a GPS receiver to a PC, the user will have a mobile device with an integrated GPS receiver.
2. Location data will be sent over mobile network using GPRS data connection to a server side.
3. The data will be processed and a KML path file will be created and updated on time intervals and used to track the user using Google Earth.

The question is: what is the best method to accomplish this scenario for the server side; is it a web service, a web application, a windows service, a windows application or what exactly? Taking into account that the system will serve a number of users simultaneously, and that more users may use the system in the future(scalability issues).

Thank you in advance and I highly appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of device are you using exactly, something like [this](http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.33331) or something more sophisticated / configurable? If we assume that the device sends its data over TCP, I would consider the following approach with separate input/output processes:

- Input: a process listening specific TCP port and storing incoming coordinates to database with a device id. Preferably, your listening loop must be able to handle [simultaneous connections](http://www.nightmare.com/medusa/async_sockets.html) without them blocking each other.
- Output: web application reading coordinates from database for a given device id and displaying them through the [Google Earth API](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/).

Use whatever programming language(s) you are familiar with.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer!!

Regarding your question about the device I'm going to use, as I said in the problem description it will be windows mobile 6 powered devices, I know that using a dedicated device like the one you noted to is much more better, but I don't want to burden the customer with more expenses, and I think that the only problem with using a mobile device with a built in GPS receiver is the battery consumption issue, which can be overcome by connecting the device to the car charger.

Comment: Regarding the suggested approach you described, wouldn't the process of storing to database then reading the stored data by a web application and displaying it on Google Earth be somehow slow and killing the essence of a real-time system?

Comment: Depends on your "realtime" resolution (1, 20, 60 secs?), but generally speaking, I don't think that database _per se_ will be not a bottleneck. To minimize delay in web application, don't use polling but HTTP push (Comet). Being not familiar with Windows/Microsoft technologies, can't help you more specifically with that.

Comment: Whoops, the above should read: "I don't think that database _per se_ will be a bottleneck."

Comment: yeah I noticed that, but knew what you meant :)

Answer (score 0):

For me there is a technical limitation/risk here -> the mobile device, and its connectivity.

1) What are your requirements? Do you need to support various mobile devices or will you focus on only one platform ?

2) More importantly, you have to understand that GPRS data connections differ from a PC connected to the Internet. There are various connection restrictions imposed by different mobile operators.

If I was to design such a system in order to minimise those risks I would go with a web server running on port 80 which the mobile devices would upload their Long/Lat through POST (or even GET to simplify things).

EDIT: Regarding scalability, it would be very easy to scale things up in the future using tried&tested load-balancing techniques.

EDIT2: Whichever technology you decide to use, i would HIGHLY recommend that the first thing you do is to mock up a prototype. Those connection restrictions could be show-stoppers. Ideally you need to explore them before you have made any serious investment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the two questions you asked:
1) For now I'm targeting windows mobile 6 powered devices, as I'm supposed to supply the customers with the devices, so it's not something commercial.
2) I understand that there is a difference, as a matter of fact I tried using Google maps for mobile on HTC Touch Diamond GPS-enabled device for the duration of 45-minute trip and it was great, and I'm talking about the real-time tracking feature of Google maps using GPS not cell-based, so I don't know what connection restrictions you are talking about, could you be more clear?

Comment: Also I have to say that I'm making a prototype or a demo to show it to the customer, of course I'm not making any thing serious :D